# How to set value of jbyte in array

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, native

I try to work with jbyte but get error:

```
 Error:(12, 19) error: no viable overloaded '='.
```

Here is my code:

```
jint len = env->GetArrayLength(s);
jbyteArray result = (env)->NewByteArray(len);
jbyte *element = env->GetByteArrayElements(s,false);
for (int i=0; i < len; i++) {
    if(env->ExceptionOccurred()) {
        break;
        }
    result[i] = *(element+i);
    }
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write into a `jbyteArray` like that. You need to use `GetByteArrayElements` to get a pointer to the underlying array. And then use `ReleaseByteArrayElements` when you're done with that array.

```
jbyte *result_bytes = env->GetByteArrayElements(result, NULL);
....
result_bytes[i] = *(element+i);
...
// 0 = copy back the modified data if necessary
env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(result, result_bytes, 0);
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html

---

By the way: the second argument to `GetByteArrayElements` is a `jboolean*`, so `GetByteArrayElements(s,false)` should be `GetByteArrayElements(s, NULL)`.
 And you need to call `ReleaseByteArrayElements` when you're done using `element`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I can't use NULL (it's undeclared)

Comment: Then include the necessary header (probably `cstddef`).